# How to get all the children of an instantiated Canvas Element Prefab

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui

I have instantiated a Scroll Rect Prefab inside a canvas and now I need to get all the children of that instantiated prefab and also the text components in each one of them.

I failed to get them with the code below.
`UIManager.uiManager.NewCanvasMenuCityPrefabs[Number]` is the reference to the instantiated canvas element prefab.

```
Transform[] Parent = UIManager.uiManager.NewCanvasMenuCityPrefabs[Number].transform.GetComponentsInChildren< Transform >();

foreach (Transform Child in Parent)
{
     print(Child);
}
```

But still I couldn't get any of the children of the element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    var canvas = UIManager.uiManager.NewCanvasMenuCityPrefabs[Number].transform;
    for (int i = 0; i < canvas.childCount; i++)
    {

       var textComponents =  canvas.GetChild(i).GetComponents<Text>();
    }
```

Comment: @SreejitPillai If this answers your question, mark it as the correct answer, please